# Hiding the table border using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a div which which displays dynamically created tables (In a asp.net repeater actually). The no of tables can be different depending on the items it gets from the database. I have given a sample markup below with the css and the jquery code. Again the table will be dynamically created. I just have given two and did not include the mark inside it.

```
.todotable{border-bottom:1px solid white;}

<div id="divalert">
<table></table>
<table></table>
</div>

 $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#divalert").last().css("border-bottom", "none");
  });
```

My question is, how do I remove the border for the last table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't selected the table. Try one of these:

```
$("#divalert :last-child").css("border-bottom", "none");

// or

$("#divalert table").last().css("border-bottom", "none");
$("#divalert table:last").css("border-bottom", "none"); // same as above
```

Comment: A slightly more efficient way would be to use `$("#divalert table:last")`, so jQuery doesn't have to select all tables and then the last from the results, but just select the last table directly.

Comment: table:last will select the last element of the table

Comment: @Josh. That's not correct. `:last` gets the last matched element of the set. `:last-child` will match the last element within the selected element.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use CSS for this. Using JS when CSS is available is never a good idea :-)

```
#divalert table:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: The websites don't have to look the same on every browser, especially on legacy ones. :-)

Comment: Preaching to the choir, but still worth noting.